# WebApi And MVC applications not running together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, single-page-application

I am facing problem while running "Asp.net WebApi with EntityFramework Identity" and "MVC SPA" in the single application, either of the one runs at a time, below is my code Global.asax > Application_Start where startup configuration is given.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ODataConfig.Register);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Which route registration calls first that only application is accessible, in above sequence only WebApis be accessible, if I change the sequence and call Application route first then only Default web application runs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if you need additional information regarding this.

thanks in advance!!

**Edit:**

All the configs are given below.

*RouteConfig:*

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

*WebApiConfig:*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

*ODataConfig:*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<Entities.Models.ListaValore>(typeof(Entities.Models.ListaValore).Name);

    var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model);

    config.EnableQuerySupport();
}
```

Comment: show us both web api route and mvc route. Looks like you messed up there.

Comment: @MahediSabuj - added the route code.

Comment: only if you are new, start from a web api template then add mvc controller, because many changes are needed to be made at global.aspx for registering api and some stuff